# Where does Voice Actions store my "Note to self" recordings?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, voice-command, voice-recording

I've been messing around with Android's [Voice Actions](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/). I tried recording various jibberish notes to test it out. However, I noticed that with each "Note to self" that I send to myself, the attached .amr recording has a suffixed number. For example, RecordedMessage2.amr, RecordedMessage3.amr and so on. It therefore occured to me that the recordings may have been saved on my phone and thus, the reason for the increment. I tried looking for those files via [OI File Mnager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.filemanager&hl=en) but failed to locate it. Can anyone help me figure out where it's being stored? I'm not rooted btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I did the "Note to Self", I was sent an email with the attachment (I assume this is the function, I've never used it before!). The attachment is the *.amr file that you can then download, and it will save it to `download/RecordedMessage#.amr`.

After some searching, **the original file is stored in phone memory, not external, at `/data/data/com.google.android.voicesearch/files/RecordedMessage#.amr`**

Note that you could not find this file because you weren't rooted, I used File X-Plore and did a search in the entire `Root` section to find them.

**Note:** If you would like to delete them:

- with root: navigate to the aforementioned folder and delete them with your favorite root browser or adb
- **without root**: from the home screen, press `Menu`, select `Settings` then choose `Applications->Manage Applications` and select `Voice Search` from the list. On the app info page select `Clear data`. This will delete all data associated with Voice Search, including any recorded "Notes to self", but keep in mind, *it may also erase any data recorded to better results on a user-by-user basis*.

Comment: Is there a way to delete them though? Surely they couldn't have made it a one-sided approach wherein data only gets written and not deletable.

Comment: @Shedo updated my answer, see **NOTE**